# automate windows tasks using image recognition

Tags: windows, ui-automation, sikuli

There are alternatives to sikuli to automate windows repetitive operations with image recognition?

Sikuli is great but it seems to not be updated since 2010 and there are no record tools.

Comment: There will probably never be a record feature for SikuliX due to the fact that it can't determine context from your actions.  However, it's pretty simple to convert AHK scripts to sikuli, and AHK has a recorder.  I'll release my solution for this once it's finished.  But as it stands, converting mouse clicks and keyboard events is super simple.

Answer (score 2):

I bookmarked your question because I was also interested in this, but I think the lack of answers actually indicates there are no alternatives. Sikuli is a great tool, and it is being updated pretty often. Check out [its Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/sikuli). The RC3 was released in December 2012 and is only 3 months old.

Also, this is what I've found on their github page:

> A new version
>
> =============
>
> is planned for January 2013. More information at: https://github.com/RaiMan/Sikuli12.11 and on Sikuli's Launchpad page:
>   https://launchpad.net/sikuli

As for record tools, yes it's a pity there aren't any, but with no alternatives it's still a fair deal to get Sikuli for free.

Comment: Just wrote a [small class for converting AHK scripts to SikuliX](https://gist.github.com/Wykleph/aad5b6b9b1eccd962caf3ca39399d525).  Only downside is it doesn't use image recognition, just the raw coordinates of the AHK clicks.  But I just ran it against a simple AHK script and it worked like a charm.  But that way, you can use the AHK recorder ;)